# Change Plot Size of ggboxplot

Tags: r, ggpubr

I created this ggboxplot (from ggpubr) with the following code in R. I want to reduce the width of the plot, i.e. get the boxes closer together. But as far as I can tell there is no way to directly manipulate plot width. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
ggboxplot(
  df_outcome.scaled, 
  x="Schedule", 
  y="Cort",
  notch = TRUE,
  width=0.2
)
```

[image]

Comment: Usually the size of the plot and therefore the width is dependent on the window size. How does it look when you export/save the plot? ie `ggsave()`. You should be able to specify dimension in the function with `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width to 0.75 and increase the aspect ratio:

```r
library(ggpubr)

ggboxplot(
  df_outcome.scaled, 
  x = "Schedule", 
  y = "Cort",
  notch = TRUE,
  width = 0.5
) + theme(aspect.ratio = 1.5)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(3)

df_outcome.scaled <- data.frame(Schedule = rep(c('Acute', 'Chronic'), 20),
                                Cort = rnorm(40, rep(c(5, 7.5), 20), 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Allan's answer is already good, but here is another quick and hacky way of changing the width using `scale_x_discrete` using the `iris` data in R. You just set the numeric limits to where you want the x and y axes to expand (positive  values widen/lengthen the plot more, whereas negative values do the opposite).

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

#### Use Scale X ####
ggboxplot(iris,
          x="Species",
          y="Petal.Width")+
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(-1,-1))
```

[image]

Another way is to manually change it's width and height in the plot window if you are exporting the plot elsewhere.

[image]